# Gateaux derivative vs Frechet derivative - what is the essential difference?

Tags: derivatives, gateaux-derivative

To a non-mathematician with a background in calculus, what is the primary difference between the two derivatives? What is happening in the infinitesimal?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative#Relation_to_the_G.C3.A2teaux_derivative